# Interpretation of the conserved current in classic Klein-Gordon and Dirac equations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation, klein-gordon-equation, classical-field-theory

The conserved current in KG is

$$j^{\mu}=i(\phi^*\partial^{\mu}\phi-\phi\partial^{\mu}\phi^*) =2p^{\mu}|N|^2$$

where N is a normalization factor. This current can't be understood as a probability current because $j^0$ can be negative. This problem is solved thinking of $j^{\mu}$ as a charge current and not probability. Then negative and positive energy solutions have opposite charges.

On the other hand, the conserved current in Dirac equation is

$$j^{\mu}=\bar{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}\psi$$

which is definite positive. This is okay because we think of this current, again, as a probability current.

Which is the correct interpretation? are conserved currents of classical equations charge currents or probability currents? Is this solved in any way in QFT?

Comment: How is this different from your previous two questions http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/311722/ and http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/311684/ ?

Comment: The Dirac $j^0=\psi^\dagger \gamma^0\psi$ is not positive definite. Even if you forget that $\psi$  is an operator, $\gamma^0$ has both positive and negative eigenvalues.

Comment: @mikestone but $j^0=\bar\psi\gamma^0\psi=\psi^\dagger\psi$, so it *is* positive definite.

Comment: @AFT  Argh....  You are right of course.  I had not yet had my morning coffee....